# How to avoid BottomBar to close and result in disposing soft keyboard

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, soft-keyboard, flutter-focus-node

When the keyboard opens, it might be causing the bottom sheet to close, which will then result in disposing any widgets inside it.

```
                    globals.addinfolistitem[widget.shotlistindex]
                            [widget.projectindex]
                        .add('Add');
                    shottypefocusnode.add(FocusNode());
                    print("FocusNode");
```

This is the one of the optiosn inside the BottomBar,the function is when the item is triggered then craete a new listitem in the container and bottombar will to close and the soft keyboard and cursor will focus on the TextFields. But now the soft keyboard is hidden.

```
  BottomBar(Widget popupmenu) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          maxHeight: globals.slidingpanelmaxheight.isNaN
              ? 500
              : globals.slidingpanelmaxheight,
          maxWidth: MediaQuery
              .of(context)
              .size
              .width - 10,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return popupmenu;
        }).then((value) {
      print("popupmenu bottom sheet closed");

      // Set focus on TextField
      if (!myFocusNode.hasFocus) {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(myFocusNode);
      }
    });
  }
```

I try to request focus again when the bottom sheet closed but doesnt work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvLVm.png)

Once the BottomBar items is triggered then add the selected item to the container and soft keyboard focus on the Textfields

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e5b7.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think I do not fully understand the problem, but as far as I understand, I hope that if you make the following structure according to one of the appropriate state management methods, it will work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  bool isBottomBarOpen = false;

  void toggleBottomBar() {
    setState(() {
      isBottomBarOpen = !isBottomBarOpen;
    });

    if (isBottomBarOpen) {
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
    } else {
      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: toggleBottomBar,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            // Your main content
            // ...
            
            // BottomBar
            if (isBottomBarOpen)
              Container(
                color: Colors.grey,
                height: 100,
                // Add your bottom bar content here
                // ...
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```